# How to draw simple graphs using tikz. beginner

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that there are numerous questions like this and I have looked at loads, but it's quite complicated for a newbie to tikz. I'm very new!

Could somebody help with just a very simple code to draw $K_3$ for example. I just want to figure out how to draw vertices and edges (not weighted or directed) between them.

I don't need a fancy example or anything as I won't understand the code!

Thank you

Comment: I don't like these kinds of answers generally, but you should really have a look at the [manual](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf). It has some tutorials in the early chapters which should be easy to follow, even for beginners, and the petri-net one (Chapter 3) can easily be modified to generate a `K_3`. In its current state your question shows very little effort on your part and any answers provided are unlikely to be useful to other people.

Comment: Also look at [this tutorial](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~hellmund/LaTeX/pgf-tut.pdf).  P.13 has an example that is almost exactly what you are asking for.  Try adapting that and then come back here with a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: What's `$K_3$`?

Comment: Probably best to look at the copy of the manual you have installed or, failing that, the one on CTAN, though. You don't want the manual for a version you don't have. @RoelofSpijker

Comment: Thank you Thruston. That tutorial is extremely helpful. Apologies I was not more specific and didn't show any work it's just because I didn't know what to try and I could have copied and pasted an answer from somewhere else but I don't know what all the different commands mean so I thought it would be pointless. Sorry and thanks

Comment: "When all else fails, read the instructions."

Comment: @cfr, you are correct :). For the sake of completeness: [current manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). As an aside, `K_n` is common notation for the complete graph on `n` vertices. Just in case you were actually asking out of interest ;)

Comment: @RoelofSpijker I guess the point was more that not everyone is familiar with such notation, so a more neutral description, or even an image, would be a lot more helpful, and understandable for most. For example, I have an inkling only because I've come across the notation in the TikZ manual.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw this question 12 hours ago and decided not to answer since the OP did not demonstrate much initiative --  especially given cfr's comment. The tikz manual is really easy to read and the commands fairly intuitive, so the OP should be able to at least start the question by themselves.

On the other hand,  Torbjørn says that not everyone is familiar with the notation. So, here is a quick "tutorial" solution that does not answer the full question but gives the OP all that they need to be able to do it themselves:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[ball color=blue](0,0) circle(2mm);% draw a ball at position (0,0)
        \shade[ball color=blue](60:1cm) circle(2mm);% draw ball with polar coords
        \draw[blue,thick](0,0)--(60:1cm);% a line between the balls
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The only parts of this MWE that is not completely obvious is that `(60:1cm)` is a polar coordinate with angle `60` degrees and distance `1cm` from the origin.

Here is the output:

[image]